# How to run c++ and get the output in a log file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

I have a c++ code got started by a shell script. The shell script has the following line to start the c++ code `/home/user/test_client/a.out` Now i want to capture the output of this code in a file called `message.log` What is the right way to do this ? I have tried `/home/user/test_client/a.out >> message.log` It doesn't work. Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem. Did you get an error?

Comment: @David Schwartz: Sorry about that. I am not getting error. The message.log file is created and its empty. and the a,out is running as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 
  a.out >> message.log 2>&1

That will also redirect stderr, which is probably where the messages are going.

Comment: Okay i will try that.. Actually the log file i am creating is inside /var/log/message.log so is there any problem with that ?

Comment: Are you running it as root? Typically users cant write to /var/log/message.log.  Try writting it to your home directory instead.

Comment: I got it sorted.. There is no output from the a.out at this stage.. It will output only in case of some errors. So thanks for that!! `2>&1` helped me in this case...

Answer (score 5):

Please use the syslog API for write to /var/log/messages

http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog